# jquery sticked scroll up and down arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css, uiscrollview

I am trying to add two sticked (UP AND DOWN) in middle of page arroys that could scroll a webpage divided into some sections. So the arrows are always in the middle appearing on the second section to the last section and letting scroll the page up or down.

[image]

currently i have a button that takes me to the top of the webpage

```
.content-wrap section .back-to-top {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -65px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    background: url(http://www.caddet-re.org/assets/images/Arrow_Circle_Up.gif);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
}
<a class="back-to-top" href="#main">Back to Top</a>
```

giving me :

[image]

[the jsfiddle is this](http://jsfiddle.net/9c58k/)

the structure of the sections is:

```
<div class="content-wrap">
     <section id="main">
      <!--content-->
      </section>

      <section id="portfolio">
      <!--content-->
     </section>
      ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code a little bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/BorisDutkin1982/ZapgY/1/

I hope that's what you mean. You can add "Down" button as well:
Just make sure it's inside the "arrows-container" and the css parameters are
the same as "Up" button except for `top:45%`,change it to `bottom:45%`.

If you want to show the arrow only after second section, you need to add
an event listener for "scrolling" and to check where the user had scrolled the page.
You can do it with `scrollTop()` method...
A code for example:

```
$(document).ready(
   function(){
      $("body").live(
         "scroll",
          function(){
             if($("body").scrollTop == NUMBER_OF_PIXELS_FROM_TOP_OF_THE_PAGE){
                $("arrow").show();
             }
          }
      );
   }
);
```

Explanaition: I added listener of scrolling action to the "body". Every time the user will scroll the body/page if the distance from the top of the page is where the second section is - show the arroa

Comment: Is there any way that the arrow is show after the second section?. I mean, in the section #main the arrows are not shown, and after that they are shown... like ´if($('selector').hasClass('main'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("main");
        $(this).addClass("hidden");
    }´  is that correct?